# Force in continuum mechanics in arbitrary coordinate system

Tags: forces, tensor-calculus, continuum-mechanics, fluid-dynamics

In my book on fluid mechanics, the force $\mathbf{F}$ is given by the surface integral over the traction vector $\mathbf{t}$.

$$\mathbf{F}=\iint_{S}\mathbf{t}dS$$

The author then introduces a relationship for the traction vector and the stress tensor $\mathbf{T} = -p\mathbf{I}+2\mu \mathbf{E}$ (assuming incompressible flow, $\mathbf{I}$ is the identity tensor and the deformation tensor $\mathbf{E}=\frac{1}{2}\left(\nabla\mathbf{u}+\nabla\mathbf{u}^T \right))$using the normal vector $\mathbf{n}$ to rewrite this expression as

$$\mathbf{F}=\iint_{S}\mathbf{n}\cdot \mathbf{T}dS.$$

Actually, I am not sure how to evaluate $\mathbf{n}\cdot \mathbf{T}$. I think it is given as the dot product of $\mathbf{n}$ with each column of $\mathbf{T}$ and the result is a column vector.

In cartesian coordinates this can be written as
$$\mathbf{n}\cdot \mathbf{T}=\begin{bmatrix}n_x\\ n_y \\ n_z \end{bmatrix}\cdot \begin{bmatrix}\tau_{xx} & \tau_{xy} & \tau_{xz}\\ \tau_{yx} & \tau_{yy} & \tau_{yz}\\ \tau_{zx} & \tau_{zy} & \tau_{zz} \end{bmatrix}=\begin{bmatrix}n_x\tau_{xx}+n_y\tau_{yx}+n_z\tau_{zx}\\n_x\tau_{xy}+n_y\tau_{yy}+n_z\tau_{zy}\\n_x\tau_{xz}+n_y\tau_{yz}+n_z\tau_{zz} \end{bmatrix}.$$

Now, I want to know how to express $\mathbf{n}\cdot\mathbf{T}$ for other coordinate systems. E.g. I want to evaluate this expression in spherical coordinates for a sphere, where $\mathbf{n}=\mathbf{e}_r$ (radial unit vector). I know $\mathbf{E}$ in different coordinate systems, but it is not clear to me how to combine everything into a coherent procedure.

Comment: Are you familiar with using dyadic notation to represent a tensor?  Also, in spherical coordinates, if the surface is not a sphere, the unit normal is not equal the radial unit vector.

Comment: $\mathbf{e}_r$ is not a constant vector (it depends on $\theta,\phi$). You can decompose $\mathbf{e}_r$ in Cartesian co-ordinates and then take the dot product, that would be simpler. However if you insist on doing it in spherical coordinates, then you must express $\mathbf{T}$ in those coordinates.

Comment: @ChesterMiller Thank you for your comment. I want to evaluate this esxpression on the surface of a sphere, I did not mention that.

Comment: @Deep So I simply enter n in cartesian coordinates and procede the same as in cartesian coirdinates?

Comment: Yes. Only on the sphere's surface $\mathbf{n}$ will be different at different points. To get $\mathbf{n}$ you take equation for sphere's surface in Cartesian coordinates and then take its gradient $\nabla$.

Comment: It's better to look up the expression for an arbitrary 2nd order tensor  in spherical coordinates (in terms of dyads involving the spherical coordinate unit vectors), and take the dot product of **e_r** with that.

Comment: @ChesterMiller: Any source for such an overview?

Comment: Transport Phenomena by Bird, Stewart, and Lightfoot, in one of the appendices.  They show in detail how to do this kind of thing.

Comment: If you wish to use matrix representation of a tensor like this, then you have to be careful about many things. The issue here is you should represent the normal vector as a row vector and not a column vector. If you were dotting the normal from the right side then it would be a column vector.